# ffmpeginterop.uwp library giving error of not registered

Tags: c#, xaml, ffmpeg, uwp, media-player

I added this library into my UWP project and tried to run a simple media file and got error of ffmpeginterop.ffmpeginteropmss not registered, following is my code.

```
            try
            {
                // Instantiate FFmpegInteropMSS using the opened local file stream
                FFmpegMSS = FFmpegInteropMSS.CreateFFmpegInteropMSSFromStream(readStream, false, false);
                MediaStreamSource mss = FFmpegMSS.GetMediaStreamSource();

                if (mss != null)
                {
                    // Pass MediaStreamSource to Media Element
                    mediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(mss);

                    // Close control panel after file open
                    Splitter.IsPaneOpen = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayErrorMessage("Cannot open media");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DisplayErrorMessage(ex.Message);
            }
```

P.S: I already have a using statement for ffmpeginterop at the top so no compiler time error occurs.

**EDIT**
problem was occuring only on my machine, temporary solved it by running the app in x64 mode and release mode. Why the problem was occuring in debug mode is still unknown.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is ... you forgot to add the decoder .dlls to your project. If the dlls are added, the .csproj have the following lines.

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)ffmpeg\Build\Windows10\$(PlatformTarget)\bin\avcodec-57.dll" />
      <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)ffmpeg\Build\Windows10\$(PlatformTarget)\bin\avdevice-57.dll" />
      <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)ffmpeg\Build\Windows10\$(PlatformTarget)\bin\avfilter-6.dll" />
      <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)ffmpeg\Build\Windows10\$(PlatformTarget)\bin\avformat-57.dll" />
      <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)ffmpeg\Build\Windows10\$(PlatformTarget)\bin\avutil-55.dll" />
      <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)ffmpeg\Build\Windows10\$(PlatformTarget)\bin\swresample-2.dll" />
      <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)ffmpeg\Build\Windows10\$(PlatformTarget)\bin\swscale-4.dll" />
```

Note - Actual path is depend on the your dev environment.

You can check the sample project that included in the FFmpegInterop project. The sample .csproject have the same section.

https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop/tree/master/Samples/SamplesWin10/MediaPlayerCS

Comment: how can I check the csproj file? I mean isn't it a project file? how can I open it in text form like you showed in your post to confirm whether it has those dll refrences? If you are asking whether I have dll files in my project folder then NO, I don't have them bcz I downloaded the library from nugget and it had no dependencies.

Comment: It was my misunderstood. I thought that you use the FFmpegInterop building from the source. If you use the NuGet package, yes, you have not to modify the .csproj to adding the decoder dll. After that, I've tried to recreate your issue. I created a simple UWP project and added the FFmpegInterop.UWP.1.0.3.  But, it works well without errors. Sorry but I have no clue about it.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code on my side. I created a blank uwp app, and install [`FFmpegInterop.UWP 1.0.3`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FFmpegInterop.UWP/) nuget package. Then using your code snippet for playing a local mp4 media file. This can work well and I cannot reproduce your issue. Since your code snippet are not the whole, here is the a complete demo which can run successfully you can test and try to find what's wrong.

XAML Code

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" Height="400" Width="400">            
   </MediaElement>
   <Button x:Name="btnplay" Click="btnplay_Click" Content="play"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
 private async void btnplay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
     openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
     openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
     openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
     openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
     openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mkv");
     StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
     using (IRandomAccessStream readStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
     {
         try
         {
             // Instantiate FFmpegInteropMSS using the opened local file stream
             var FFmpegMSS = FFmpegInteropMSS.CreateFFmpegInteropMSSFromStream(readStream, false, false);
             MediaStreamSource mss = FFmpegMSS.GetMediaStreamSource();
             if (mss != null)
             {
                 // Pass MediaStreamSource to Media Element
                 mediaElement.SetMediaStreamSource(mss);
                 // Close control panel after file open
                 //Splitter.IsPaneOpen = false;
             }
             else
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot open media");
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((ex.Message));
         }
     }
 }
```

I tested on local machine window 10 build 14393. More details please reference [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/using-ffmpeg-in-windows-applications/#CihO5g2VM2Jpuc4D.97). And [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop/issues/11) is a similar issue with you which you may try to reference.

Comment: I also have build 14393 and I copy pasted ur XAML and c# and still getting exactly the same error as before :( it just doesn't make any sense, what mode did u debug? x84 or x64 in visual studio for this project?

Comment: converted the build to x63 in visual studio and now it runs an mp4 file but it displays the video for 2, 3 seconds and then media seekbar goes straight to the end of the video, and if I press play button again it gives decoding failed error written over media player.

Comment: @touseef  I cannot reproduce the only play 2-3 seconds issue, please check if something wrong with your mp4 file itself. Duplicate play may lead error since the file is already opened for reading.